# Mock a method in enum using PHPunit Mockery in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, mocking, phpunit, mockery

I have run into a problem when mocking Enums using Mockery + PHPUnit in PHP 8.1 (im using the laravel  framework but I'm not sure this is relevant).

I have defined an enum:

```
<?php namespace MyNamespace\Enums;

enum MyEnum {

    case A;
    case B;

    public function method1(): string {
        return match ($this) {
            self::A => 'A',
            self::B => 'B',
        };
    }

}
```

I am trying to mock MyEnum. I have created a test that looks something like this:

```
public function testShouldCanReturnsB() {
    $mock = \Mockery::mock('\MyNamespace\Enums\MyEnum');
    $mock->shouldReceive('method1')->andReturn('B');
}
```

When I run the test I receive the message:

```
Mockery\Exception : The class \MyNamespace\Enums\MyEnum is marked final and its methods cannot be replaced. Classes marked final can be passed in to \Mockery::mock() as instantiated objects to create a partial mock, but only if the mock is not subject to type hinting checks.
```

How could I mock the method inside Enum?

Comment: You cannot mock Enums, they are [`final`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.final.php) on PHP (means you cannot extend the class, in this case Mockery extends the class when mocking). You need to mock what is inside of it. Could you share your real code? And it is very relevant that it is Laravel, helps a lot related to testing

Comment: In the first place why are you trying to mock an enum, your case seems very straight forward and if you have complex logic in your enum seperate it out and mock a service / action where you perform that operation.